# Color duplicates rows in two different sets of data and also the rows which are present in both sets of data

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, automation

## Note

***When I say `rows`, I mean cells in <kbd>Column A</kbd> only and not the whole row.***

## Background

There are two sets of data. Lets call the data on the top, **Data A** and data on the bottom, **Data B**

I have made a Macro (VBA provided at the bottom) that:

1. Clears the Conditional Formatting on the entire sheet.
2. Highlights all duplicate ***`rows`*** as Red.
3. Highlights all duplicate ***`rows`*** in **Data A** as Green.
4. Highlights all non-empty cells in *Column E* as Yellow.
5. Sorts **Data A** in the following order. Red cells in *Column A*, Green cells in *Column A*, Yellow cells in *Column E*, *Column A* Values Ascending, *Column D* Values Ascending.

In simple words it;
a) marks duplicate ***`rows`*** present in both **Data A** & **Data B** as red
b) marks duplicate ***`rows`*** of **Data A** as Green.

## Requirements

Now I want the Macro to work this way:

1. Clears the Conditional Formatting on the entire sheet.
2. Duplicate ***`rows`*** of whole data should be Highlighted Red
3. Duplicate ***`rows`*** in **Data A** that are also present in **Data B** should all be Highlighted Blue
4. Duplicate ***`rows`*** present only in **Data A** should be Highlighted Green
5. Any non-blank cells in *Column E* should be Yellow
6. Sorts **Data A** in the following order. Red cells in *Column A*, Blue cells in *Column A*, Green cells in *Column A*, Yellow cells in *Column E*, *Column A* Values Ascending, *Column D* Values Ascending.

## Question

How do I do this? What should I change/add in the macro for it to meet the requirements? If that is difficult, please tell me how to do this manually with conditional formatting or formulae, I will convert it into a macro myself.

## This is the VBA of my Macro:

```
'
'
'Declaration
'
'
    Dim MyRange As String
    Dim Rough As String
    Dim A_To_Q As String
    Dim A_To_E As String
    Dim A_To_F As String
    Dim ColumnA As String
    Dim ColumnC As String
    Dim ColumnD As String
    Dim ColumnE As String
    Dim ColumnF As String
'
'
'Assignment
'
'
    MyRange = ActiveCell.Address(0, 0) & ":" & "E1"
'
    Rough = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).AddressLocal & ":" & "Q1"
    A_To_Q = Mid(Rough, 2, 1) & Mid(Rough, 4, 6)
    Rough = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Address & ":" & "E1"
    A_To_E = Mid(Rough, 2, 1) & Mid(Rough, 4, 6)
    Rough = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Address & ":" & "F1"
    A_To_F = Mid(Rough, 2, 1) & Mid(Rough, 4, 6)
    Rough = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Address & ":" & "A1"
    ColumnA = Mid(Rough, 2, 1) & Mid(Rough, 4, 6)
    Rough = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Address & ":" & "C1"
    ColumnC = Mid(Rough, 2, 1) & Mid(Rough, 4, 6)
    Rough = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Address & ":" & "D1"
    ColumnD = Mid(Rough, 2, 1) & Mid(Rough, 4, 6)
    Rough = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Address & ":" & "E1"
    ColumnE = Mid(Rough, 2, 1) & Mid(Rough, 4, 6)
    Rough = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Address & ":" & "F1"
    ColumnF = Mid(Rough, 2, 1) & Mid(Rough, 4, 6)
'
'
'Formating
'
'
    Cells.FormatConditions.Delete
'
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.AddUniqueValues
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).DupeUnique = xlDuplicate
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .Color = -16383844
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 13551615
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
'
    Range(ColumnA).Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.AddUniqueValues
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).DupeUnique = xlDuplicate
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .Color = -16752384
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 13561798
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
'
    Range(ColumnE).Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
        "=LEN(TRIM(E1))>0"
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .Color = -16751204
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 10284031
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
'
'
'Sorting
'
'
Range(A_To_F).Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add(Range(ColumnA), _
        xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = RGB(255, _
        199, 206)
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add(Range(ColumnA), _
        xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = RGB(198, _
        239, 206)
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add(Range(ColumnE), _
        xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = RGB(255, _
        235, 156)
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range(ColumnA) _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range(ColumnD) _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
        .SetRange Range(A_To_F)
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
```

Comment: Under **Question** you state: *Now I want the Macro to work this way:* and then you list some requirements, but you never ask anything. So, **what is the question**

Comment: @TomBrunberg I have edited the post. to include the text. My question is "What should I change/add in the macro for it to meet the requirements? If that is difficult, please tell me how to do this manually with conditional formatting or formulae, I will convert it into a macro myself."

Answer (score 1):

The code below is not include the sorting process.
If I understand you correctly AND if you don't mind using a helper column...

Before and After running the sub

[image] ===> [image]

in upper section:
green: duplicate value only found in upper section
blue/magenta: duplicate value is also found in lower section
yellow (red in your case): it's a part of duplicate from lower section.

```
Sub test()
Dim rg As Range: Dim addrA As String: Dim addrB As String
Dim arr: Dim el

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set rg = Range("A1", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
addrA = Split(rg.SpecialCells(xlConstants).Address, ",")(0)
addrB = Split(rg.SpecialCells(xlConstants).Address, ",")(1)

For Each cell In rg.Offset(0, 4).SpecialCells(xlConstants)
cell.Interior.Color = vbBlue
Next

With rg.Offset(0, 100)
    .Value = "=if(countif(" & rg.Address & "," & _
    Replace(rg(1, 1).Address, "$", "") & ")>1,true,"""")"
    .SpecialCells(xlFormulas, xlLogical).Offset(0, -100).Interior.Color = vbYellow
    .Clear
End With

With Range(addrA).Offset(0, 100)
    .Value = "=if(countif(" & addrA & "," & _
    Replace(Range(addrA)(1, 1).Address, "$", "") & ")>1,true,"""")"
    Set rgR = .SpecialCells(xlFormulas, xlLogical).Offset(0, -100)
    .Clear
End With

rgR.Interior.Color = vbGreen
Set arr = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
For Each cell In rgR: arr.Item(cell.Value) = 1: Next

For Each el In arr
If Not Range(addrB).Find(el, lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then
With Range(addrA)
    .Replace el, True, xlWhole, , False, , False, False
    .SpecialCells(xlConstants, xlLogical).Interior.Color = vbCyan
    .Replace True, el, xlWhole, , False, , False, False
End With
End If
Next
    
End Sub
```

Please make sure there's nothing in column 101.
the rg is the data range in column A.
addrA value is the address of the upper section.
addrB value is the address of the lower section.

Basically the code just check each cell value in rg if the total count of it's value is > 1 then it fill with yellow.

Then it check each cell value in range addrA address (the upper section), if the total count of it's value is > 1 then it fill with green. The yellow in the upper section turn into green.

Then it check IF within the green address of the upper section the value is also found in lower section, then the green turn into blue.